# Does new URL(...).openConnection() necessarily imply a POST?

Tags: java, http, url

If I create an HTTP `java.net.URL` and then call `openConnection()` on it, does it necessarily imply that an HTTP post is going to happen?  I know that `openStream()` implies a GET.  If so, how do you perform one of the other HTTP verbs without having to work with the raw socket layer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you retrieve the `URLConnection` object using `openConnection()` it doesn't actually start communicating with the server.  That doesn't happen until you get the stream from the `URLConnection()`.  When you first get the connection you can add/change headers and other connection properties before actually opening it.

URLConnection's life cycle is a bit odd.  It doesn't send the headers to the server until you've gotten one of the streams.  If you just get the input stream then I believe it does a GET, sends the headers, then lets you read the output.  If you get the output stream then I believe it sends it as a POST, as it assumes you'll be writing data to it (You may need to call `setDoOutput(true)` for the output stream to work).  As soon as you get the input stream the output stream is closed and it waits for the response from the server.

For example, this should do a POST:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://example.com/my/path");
URLConnection conn = myURL.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write("Hi there!");
os.close();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
// read stuff here
```

While this would do a GET:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://example.com/my/path");
URLConnection conn = myURL.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
// read stuff here
```

`URLConnection` will also do other weird things.  If the server specifies a content length then `URLConnection` will keep the underlying input stream open until it receives that much data, *even if you explicitly close it*.  This caused a lot of problems for us as it made shutting our client down cleanly a bit hard, as the `URLConnection` would keep the network connection open.  This probably probably exists even if you just use `getStream()` though.

Answer (score 3):

No it does not. But if the protocol of the URL is HTTP, you'll get a [`HttpURLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) as a return object. This class has a `setRequestMethod` method to specify which HTTP method you want to use.

If you want to do more sophisticated stuff you're probably better off using a library like [Jakarta HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).